# OutOfMemory exception in WPF video rendering application with COM interop

Tags: c#, wpf, com-interop, sta

We have a rich client application developed using WPF/C#.Net 4.0 which interops with in-house COM DLLs.  Regular events are raised via this COM interface containing video data.

As part of the application we render video via Windows Media Foundation and have created interops to use Window Media Foundation.  We have multiple WMF pipelines rendering different video at the same time.

The application runs for 6-8 hours rendering video.  Private bytes remaining consistently steady during this time (say around 500-600MB).

At some point the application appears to hang, at this point private bytes increases very rapidly until the process consumes approximately 1.4GB of memory and crashes with an OutOfMemoryException.

We have reproduced this on 5 different workstations with different graphic cards (NVIDIA and ATI cards) and a mixture of Windows 7 32 and 64bit.

We have analyzed 3 dump files and found that the finalizer thread is waiting on a call to the ole32.GetToSTA() method. We are unable to determine what causes the finalizer thread to block and how to resolve this.  I have pasted excerpts from three dumps we've been analyzing:

Dump 1)

Thread 2:ae0 is waiting on an STA thread efc

Thread 28:efc is calling a WaitForSingleObject.  The handle it is waiting on is actually a thread handle 5ab4 which is thread id 14a4

Thread 130:14a4 has the following stack:

```
37f4fdf4 753776a6 ntdll!NtRemoveIoCompletion+0x15
37f4fe20 63301743 KERNELBASE!GetQueuedCompletionStatus+0x29
37f4fe74 6330d0db WMNetMgr!CNSIoCompletionPortNT::WaitAndServeCompletionsLoop+0x5e
37f4fe94 633199bf WMNetMgr!CNSIoCompletionPortNT::WaitAndServeCompletions+0x4c
37f4fecc 63312dbd WMNetMgr!CWorkThreadManager::CWorkerThread::ThreadMain+0xa2
37f4fed8 769b3677 WMNetMgr!CWMThread::ThreadFunc+0x3b
37f4fee4 77679f42 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
37f4ff24 77679f15 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
37f4ff3c 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

Dump2)

STA thread:

```
1127f474 75f80a91 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x15
1127f4e0 77411184 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x98
1127f4f8 77411138 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectExImplementation+0x75
1127f50c 63ae5f29 kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
1127f530 63a8eb2e WMNetMgr!CWMThread::Wait+0x78
1127f54c 63a8f128 WMNetMgr!CWorkThreadManager::CThreadPool::Shutdown+0x70
1127f568 63a76e10 WMNetMgr!CWorkThreadManager::Shutdown+0x34
1127f59c 63a76f2d WMNetMgr!CNSClientNetManagerHelper::Shutdown+0xdd
1127f5a4 63cd228e WMNetMgr!CNSClientNetManager::Shutdown+0x66
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
1127f5bc 63cd23a6 WMVCORE!WMCreateProfileManager+0xeef6
1127f5dc 63c573ca WMVCORE!WMCreateProfileManager+0xf00e
1127f5e8 63c62f18 WMVCORE!WMIsAvailableOffline+0x2ba3b
1127f618 63c19da6 WMVCORE!WMIsAvailableOffline+0x37589
1127f630 63c1aca2 WMVCORE!WMIsContentProtected+0x56e4
1127f63c 63c14bd7 WMVCORE!WMIsContentProtected+0x65e0
1127f650 113de6e8 WMVCORE!WMIsContentProtected+0x515
1127f660 113de513 wmp!CWMDRMReaderStub::CExternalStub::ShutdownInternalRefs+0x1d0
1127f674 113c1988 wmp!CWMDRMReaderStub::ExternalRelease+0x4f
1127f67c 1160a5b9 wmp!CWMDRMReaderStub::CExternalStub::Release+0x13
1127f6a4 1161745f wmp!CWMGraph::CleanupUpStream_selfprotected+0xbe
```

Finalizer thread is trying to switch to STA:

```
0126eccc 75f80a91 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x15
0126ed38 77411184 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x98
0126ed50 77411138 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectExImplementation+0x75
0126ed64 75d78907 kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
0126ed88 75e9a819 ole32!GetToSTA+0xad
```

Dump3)

The finalizer thread is in the GetToSTA call, so it is waiting for a COM object to free

Thread 29 is a COM object in the STA, and it is waiting on a critical section owned by thread 53 (1bf4)

Thread 53 is doing:

```
1cbcf990 76310a91 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x15
1cbcf9fc 74cb1184 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x98
1cbcfa14 74cb1138 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectExImplementation+0x75
1cbcfa28 65dfb6bb kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
1cbcfa48 74cb3677 wmp!Ordinal3000+0x53280
1cbcfa54 77029f42 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
1cbcfa94 77029f15 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x701cbcfaac 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

Any ideas on how we might resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the finalizer thread is deadlocked.  That will certainly result in an eventual OOM.  We can't see the full stack trace for the finalizer thread but some odds that you'll see SwitchAptAndDispatchCall() and ReleaseRCWListInCorrectCtx() in the trace, indicating that it is trying to call IUnknown::Release() to release a COM object.  And that object is apartment threaded so a thread switch is required to safely make the call.

I don't see any decent candidates in the stack traces you posted, possibly because you didn't get the right one or the thread is already busy shutting down due to the exception.  Try to catch it earlier with a debugger break as soon as you see the virtual memory size climb.

The most common cause for a deadlock like this is violating the requirements for an STA thread.  Which state that it must never block and must pump a message loop.  The never-block requirement is typically easily met in a .NET program, the CLR will pump a message loop when necessary when you use the *lock* statement or a WaitHandle.WaitXxx() call.  It is however very common to forget to pump a message loop, especially since doing so is kinda painful.  Application.Run() is required.

Comment: Thanks Hans. We seem to reliably see calls into Windows Media-related assemblies (WMNetMgr, WMVCORE, WMP) on the blocking STA thread. We don't know exactly how this thread is created yet - presumably somewhere in the MediaFoundation implementation. We've noticed that this particular line is in most/all stacktraces: 20d87aac 31177aa0 c00d2ee0 wmp!CWMPGraphGenerator::NotifyGraphError+0x670 It would be good to know what the error code being referred to means.

Comment: That too is likely a side-effect of the OOM.  Kinda important you nip this in the butt before everything falls over.  Focus on threading, the ultimate source of the problem.  And don't hesitate to consider calling Microsoft Support for help, there's a lot of code here you didn't write.

Comment: Thanks, Microsoft have been contacted.  If there's a resolution I'll post an update.

Comment: Hi Kate. Did you ever get to the bottom of this? We have virtually the same issue (plus a small leak every time an event crosses from COM, through the interop, into a WPF/C# event handler).